# Find the end of a list in Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm new to x86 Assembly. I encountered a question in the book I'm learning from:

> We have discussed three approaches to finding the end of the list: using a special number, using the ending address and using the length count. Which approach do you think is best? Why? Which approach would you use if you knew that the list was sorted? Why?

Using a special number refers to putting a number at the end of the list and stopping when reached to that.

I can't figure out the answer. Which approach is more effective? Why? How does a sorted list differ from normal list in finding the end? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to define which list you are using. Serial list? Linked list? Circular list?

Comment: Is this a linked list or an array? In either case, having a pointer to the end is obviously the best way to find the end :) For an array, the length is almost as good, you just add that to the start. Special number always means you have to scan the entire list. For a sorted list you don't need a constant terminator, you can choose it dynamically such that it goes against the sort order. This has the advantage that you can store all numbers in your list, you don't have to designate a special value which itself can not be part of the list. There is still the problem of the empty list though.

Comment: Book hasn't specified whether it is an array or linked list. I suppose the question covers both. Thanks, it is clear now.

Comment: It's an open-ended question.  Different approaches would be best in different cases.  The question is meant to make you think about the pros and cons of each, what the tradeoffs would be, and how you might choose between them for particular applications.  But there isn't a single right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best for what purpose?  Size efficiency?  Implicit-length C-strings are pretty compact, just costing 1 extra byte for the terminator, not a whole extra pointer.

But for performance, explicit-length strings and arrays are much easier to work with especially using SIMD: you can check that there are at least N elements left before entering an unrolled loop.  Compare glibc's x86-64 SSE2 implementations of `memchr` vs `strchr`: you really have to jump through hoops with `strchr` to make sure you don't read into an unmapped page if the end of the string is right at the end of a page.

- https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/memchr.S.html
  alignment handling could be simpler for sizes >= 16 bytes, but actually glibc chooses to avoid cache-line splits.  But note [the main loop](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/memchr.S.html#173), once it reaches a 64-byte alignment boundary: the loop condition based on end-of-buffer is just `sub $64, %rdx` / `jbe  L(exit_loop)`, without any per-byte work.
- https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/strchr.S.html
  Note the `andl  $4095, %eax` / `cmpl  $4032, %eax` to check for being near a page-crossing, and the extra SIMD work to check for `0` as well as the target character in each of the 16 bytes being checked in parallel.